# How can I show child-item count in SharePoint - online 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, count, sharepoint-2007

I need to show the number of files in a folder in SharePoint 2007. I know in 2010 there is a column you can add that shows this, but I can't figure out how to do it in 2007. [This](http://weblogs.asp.net/sharadkumar/archive/2008/06/27/showing-child-items-in-hierarchical-sharepoint-lists-with-multiple-content-types.aspx) tutorial seems to show how to do it, but I don't have access to the Schema.xml since it's all online. Does anyone know how I might be able to do this?